# Does Java's floating point implementation still have the problems identified by Kahan?

Tags: java, floating-point

I've read a few papers from Kahan tonight, and his [famous rant](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/JAVAhurt.pdf) against Java.  Before I dive into the JVM spec, did anything change since the initial rant on this front?  For example:

- setting rounding mode
- accessing the flags
- getting more precision for free
- ... ?

Thanks,

Nico.

Comment: This question may need to be rephrased. This seems to be leading towards discussion.

Comment: I made the title a specific question to reduce the chance that this question will be summarily closed as trying to evoke discussion rather than seeking an answer.

Comment: Wow, that's a fascinating paper. Is C# just as bad?

Comment: Chris > no, it's a little bit better, I've been into the CLR spec (it's faster than the JVM's one), and it gives you the opportunity to use the native float size. But no explicit access to the rounding mode or flags or traps.

Comment: @nraynaud, how can one *spec* be faster than another?

Comment: If I remember well, I meant "it's faster to read than ...", but it was 3 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prof. Kahan's student, Joe Darcy, became Sun's "floating point czar".  His blog entry ["Everything Old is New Again"](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/everything_old_is_new_again), is an entry point for learning more about work he did to correct the problems.  There have been great improvements.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't adress the rant. 
But it hints at the fact that there is no change in the fp system.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is they are still valid as I have not seen much change in this area since '98.

However, I am not sure they would really be used much even if they were added today.  Many languages support variable precision arithmetic (as does Java) which appears to be a better solution for this type of problem. e.g. BigInteger, BigDecimal.

Comment: "Arbitrary precision", not "variable precision". Together with changes to the floating point semantics in Java 2.0 (1.2) the arbitrary precision types give a good answer to Kahan's complaints. Not that I'm a numerical analyst myself.

Comment: I should confess that I've never seen a matrix inversion or a Kalman predictor in arbitrary precision. I'm not sure this is the right tool for numerical simulation.